# Adding $w$ to a bases vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

Given that $v_1,v_2,...,v_m$ is a linearly independent list and $w\in V$ where $V$ is a vector space over an arbitrary scalar field $\mathbf{F}$. My intuition tells me that provided $w\not\in\{-v_1,-v_2,...,-v_m\}$ the list $v_1+w,v_2+w,...,v_m+w$ will be linearly independent in $V$ Is my conjecture correct? **If so please do not present the proof here.**

Comment: Does the list $v_1, v_2, ... v_m$ form a basis for $V$? If so, then no. If not, then maybe. There isn't enough information to say for sure if any arbitrary vector $w$ is added that the list will be linearly independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the following counterexample:

$v_1 = (1, 0) \\
v_2 = (0, 1) \\
w = (-\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2})$

Then you have that:

$a + w + b+w = 0$ so they are not linerly independent.

It is true, however, when w is linearly independent from the elements of the list.